# What's the preferred way to write this code when both achieve the same thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function here that loops through two wrappers and then loops through it's respective children and throws it a number to list out items in numerical order.  Instead of using a for loop, I've decided to use the each jQuery function.  Here is my question:

Which way is better to achieve this and what are the advantages/disadvantages by going one way or the other??  Is it better to use a for loop??

This:

```
$(".articleContentWrapper").each( function () { 
    var i = 1;
    $(this).find(".howToStepNumber").each(function () {
        var b = i++;
        $(this).html(b);
    });
});
```

Or this:

```
$(".articleContentWrapper").each( function () { 
    var i = 1;
    $(this).find(".howToStepNumber").each(function () {
        $(this).html(i++);
    });
});
```

Comment: There are no advantages to `var b = i++; $(this).html(b);`. You're just wasting memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
$(".articleContentWrapper").each( function () { 
    $(this).find(".howToStepNumber").each(function (i, e) {
        $(this).html(i + 1);
    });
});
```

The `.each()` method already provides an index holder so you don't need to create one yourself.

Comment: In OP code `i` starts from 1 :P

Comment: What's the `e` being passed in `.each` represent?

Comment: That is the DOM Element of the index. So you could also write `$(e).html(i + 1);` instead of `$(this).html(i + 1);`

Comment: @SethenMaleno http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: I am under the impression that it's better not to try and pass a variable that needs to be incremented within the `html` function itself.  Rather, to increment before.

Comment: Why not? It's like an calculation function that returns an value which is passed as a parameter into the `.html();` method.

Comment: I guess I am assuming that it wastes resources doing it within the `html()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
var wrapper = $(".articleContentWrapper");
$(".howToStepNumber", wrapper).text( function (i) { 
    return ( i % (wrapper.length + 1) ) + 1;
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kVUBu/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try like below,

```
$(".howToStepNumber", $(".articleContentWrapper")).html( function () {
    return $(this).index() + 1;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rJAgJ/1/)

Comment: I really like this one. A nice approach.

Comment: I've never seen it written like `$(".howToStepNumber", $(".articleContentWrapper"))` how does that work?

Comment: It is equivalent to `$(".articleContentWrapper").find ('.howToStepNumber')`

Comment: @Vega thanks for clearing that up.  Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write it as:

```
$(".articleContentWrapper").each( function () { 
    $(".howToStepNumber", this).each(function (i) {
        $(this).html(i);  // or i+1 depending on what you want
    });
});
```

The find really isn't necessary either and makes the statement longer.